# Creating sqlite db in Python 3 with constructed f string and receiving: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, operationalerror

I am trying to create a sqlite3 db table using a constructed f string in python 3, however I am receiving the below error:

`sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`

I had hoped that I wouldn't need to ask here for a syntax error but I have been searching on stackoverflow as well as generally online to identify the issue with no success.
I have compared the code to other samples and equally do not see any difference to the construction, except for that it doesn't appear to be common to use f strings.

I have read the pros/cons of passing parameters and would prefer this f string unless it is the root cause.

I expect the issue might be obvious, however any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the full code:

```
    import sqlite3
    import pandas as pd
    
    db_path = [PATH TO DATABASE]
    db_table_name = [TABLE NAME]
    header_source = [PATH TO .XLSX]
    
    def ReadHeaders():
    
        df = pd.read_excel(header_source)

        col_list = list(df.columns.values)
    
        prep_col_list = [item.replace(" ", "_") for item in col_list]
    
        col_string = " TEXT, _".join(prep_col_list)
    
        final_col_string = col_string.replace("Primary_ID TEXT", "Primary_ID PRIMARY KEY")
    
        return final_col_string
    
        
    def CreateSQLdb():
    
        cols = ReadHeaders()
    
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)

        c = conn.cursor()
    
        c.execute(f""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {db_table_name} ({cols}) """)
    
        conn.commit()

        conn.close()
```

A sample of the string that is created for the table headers is:

```
_link TEXT, _Primary_ID PRIMARY KEY, _Status_Description TEXT, _Price_List_Status TEXT, _Brand TEXT, _36_Character_Description TEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

After breaking everything down, the root cause was the constructed string. I was able to identify it when trying to export the constructed string to a .txt file and received a unicode error.

Code before:

```
return final_col_string
```

Code after:

```
return final_col_string.encode(encoding="utf-8")
```

I also added a simple check of the table info for confirmation

```
def ShowTable(c):

    c.execute(f"PRAGMA table_info({db_table_name})")

    print (c.fetchall())
```

Complete code encase anyone else comes across this issue:

```
    import sqlite3
    import pandas as pd
    
    db_path = [PATH TO DATABASE]
    db_table_name = [TABLE NAME]
    header_source = [PATH TO .XLSX]
    
    def ReadHeaders():
    
        df = pd.read_excel(header_source)

        col_list = list(df.columns.values)
    
        prep_col_list = [item.replace(" ", "_") for item in col_list]
    
        col_string = " TEXT, _".join(prep_col_list)
    
        final_col_string = col_string.replace("Primary_ID TEXT", "Primary_ID PRIMARY KEY")
    
        return final_col_string.encode(encoding="utf-8")
    
        
    def CreateSQLdb():
    
        cols = ReadHeaders()
    
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)

        c = conn.cursor()
    
        c.execute(f""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {db_table_name} ({cols}) """)
    
        conn.commit()

        conn.close()

    def ShowTable(c):

        c.execute(f"PRAGMA table_info({db_table_name})")

        print (c.fetchall())


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        CreateSQLdb()
```